# remapping in launch files

Tags: ros, roslaunch, camera1394, dynamic-reconfigure, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have created a launch file that launches the camera1394 driver and displays the color image using the image_proc and image_view packages.

I am also trying to launch the dynamic_reconfigure node and connect it to the camera1394 node, however I am having a problem with the remapping, here is what I am trying to do in my launch file:

```
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="testserver" name="dynamic_reconfigure">
  <remap from="XXX" to="camera1394_nodelet/parameter_updates" />
</node>
```

I am not sure where to get the XXX name from? Could someone please tell me where I can find the names of the inputs/outputs of a node(in general)from?

Thanks and regards,
Khalid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51107/remapping-in-launch-files/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remap is for topics.

To bring up reconfigure_gui connected to that particular node, pass the node name as a command line argument:

```
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="reconfigure_gui" name="camera_gui"
      args="camera1394_nodelet" />
```

That should be equivalent to this command line:

```
$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui camera1394_nodelet
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2012-12-27**:
Thank you for your response, I added this line to my launch file, however the reconfigure_gui still does not pop up, I checked the nodes using rqt_gui and a node named reconfigure_gui appears but it is not connected to the driver or anything?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-12-28**:
If you want the reconfigure_gui, you should use reconfigure_gui not the testserver executable.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-28**:
Oops! Thanks, Tully, for pointing out that I had the parameters backwards. Fixed in the answer now.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2012-12-28**:
Thanks for the answer guys, this solves this issue.